# sails.js how to call a REST API from a script using restler or not?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I haven't figured out how to get a response from restler in sails.js script. The goal is to import some data each day from a REST API to my database. So I chose to use sails.js script to be able to crontab the call.

When I search what I could use to contact the API. I saw a topic about [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler#example-usage) which seem pretty easy to use.

Sadly when I try it I cannot catch the response from the API, I use this basic example

```js
module.exports = {

  friendlyName: 'test',

  description: 'this is a test',

  fn: async function () {

    sails.log('Running custom shell script... (`sails run test`)');
    var rest = require('restler');
    rest.get('http://google.com').on('complete', function(result) {
      sails.log("In callback")
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        sails.log('Error:', result.message);
        this.retry(5000); // try again after 5 sec
      } else {
        sails.log(result);
      }
    });
    sails.log('finished');
  }


};
```

When I run the script this is what I get

```js
 info: Initializing hook... (`api/hooks/custom`)
 info: Initializing `apianalytics` hook...  (requests to monitored routes will be logged!)
 info: ·• Auto-migrating...  (alter)
 info:    Hold tight, this could take a moment.
 info:  ✓ Auto-migration complete.

debug: Running custom shell script... (`sails run test`)
debug: finished
```

I try other method and other URL too, but apparently I never get in the callback.
So I assume that the script doesn't "wait" the `.on('complete')` before continuing his execution.

I know, and use, on the database call `.then` to avoiding that, I think this is called a 'promise'. So from what I understand the problem is around that but sadly after searching, I don't find any answer to solve my issue.

I am not married to restler, and if another and better solution exists don't hesitate, the goal is again to get the content from a REST API from sails.js script.

Thank you for the time you take to answer my question.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623547/6309457

Comment: rester updated last in 2015, and sails updated version so use new solution.

Comment: I try the first exemple in the doc and still have the same issue when using ` var rp = require('request-promise');`.

Comment: Drop async, just use npm request, forget promises.